# How to ignore certain fetch requests in cypress cy.visit

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

When calling `cy.visit("https://my-page.com")` my page will fetch a number of external libraries/scripts. One of them is for `sentry.io`. Sometimes this particular fetch will just hang forever. The website is perfectly usable without it. Is there a way to make `cy.visit` not wait for these fetch requests from certain domains?

Answer (score 4):

Some things to try, depends on how the app responds

[Controlling the response](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Controlling-the-response)

> req.destroy() - destroy the request and respond with a **network error**

```js
cy.intercept('https://sentry.io/*', req => req.destroy())
```

> req.reply() - stub out a response requiring no dependency on a real back-end

```js
cy.intercept('https://sentry.io/*', {})  // stubbed, never goes to the server
```

You may have to tweak `{}` to include fake properties if the app expects them.

Comment: I am unable to resolve using above solution. my requirement is when i invoke  cy.visit(https://www.saucedemo.com/), it is fetching some of the "events.backtrace" apis and they are failing with 401, so on cypress my test failing, so i gave cy.intercept('https://events.backtrace.io/api/*', req => req.destroy()) before cy.visit() still same issue, Help me in resolve it